# Different Sorting Orders - divide and conquer?

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I'm trying to re-arrange a list of objects in different ways. Here I'll use integers but could be anything in this list.

The example code below sorts `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` into the following order:
`1,8,2,7,3,6,4,5`

So first. last. second. Second to last etc. It may be a bit clunky but it works.

Now what I'm trying to do now is to output the list in another order, so that it keeps dividing in two. I think this may be called Divide and Conquer but after trying / looking at some recursive sorting code etc. I'm not too clear on how to implement that here.

I hope to get the numbers ordered like this.

```
1,8,4,2,6,3,5,7
```

First, last, halfway, 1st half halfway, 2nd half halfway etc.

So in other words what I'm trying to do is to split the set of numbers in half... Then for each half in turn split those in half. And so on:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1                      (first item)
              8        (last item)
      4                (mid item)
  2                     (mid of first half) 
          6              (mid of second half)
    3                    (mid of 1st chunk)
        5                (mid of 2nd chunk)
           7             (mid of 3rd chunk)
```

If anyone could anyone show me how to do this, with this simple example, that'd be really great.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<int> numberlist = new List<int>();

        numberlist.Add(1);
        numberlist.Add(2);
        numberlist.Add(3);
        numberlist.Add(4);
        numberlist.Add(5);
        numberlist.Add(6);
        numberlist.Add(7);
        numberlist.Add(8);

        int rev = numberlist.Count-1;
        int fwd = 0;

        // order 1,8,2,7,3,6,4,5

        for (int re = 0; re < numberlist.Count; re++)
        {
            if (re % 2 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(numberlist[fwd]);
                fwd++;                       
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(numberlist[rev]);
                rev--;
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Some more sample ranges and output, to be read left-to-right, top-to-bottom:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1           7
      4
  2     5
    3     6

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
1                       12
          6 
    3           9 
  2   4     7     10
        5     8      11


1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
1                                   16
              8 
      4                 12
  2       6       10          14
    3   5   7   9    11    13    15
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have a clear pattern to me. Can you expand on the pattern?

Comment: I agree with Kyle -- I think if you can more clearly describe the pattern you're going for, it will be easier to implement the code. Can you "work" an example? (That is, show us in more detail the steps by which you arrive at a desired order.) What would be really helpful is to work (1) an extremely small example; say, only four items, (2) a medium-sized example, and (3) a large example, say with sixteen items in it. That should help demonstrate any recursive pattern.

Comment: Thanks, yer sorry I had a mistake. It's correct now.. should have ended ...3,5,7. I've added a worked example.. does that make sense now?

Comment: What's the order that each subrange should be processed? Least to greatest? Are the additional samples correct?

Comment: Yes thanks outis.. those examples seem correct.

Comment: Are you just ordering numbers, or strings as well?

Comment: Hi Brian.. I'm actually wanting to order points (spatial, GIS).. but it could be anything. The index of the list will always be an int and that's all that really matters.. it's how to select stuff in a particular order based on that index. An example using ints was just easier to explain.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let me see if I understand the problem. Let's work an example with more items:

This is the order you want?

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ
A               Q  
        I
    E       M
  C   G   K   O
 B D F H J L N P
```

That seems straightforward.  Create a data structure called "Interval" that has two fields: the Greatest Lower Bound and the Least Upper Bound. That is, what are the elements that are the *biggest thing that is below the interval* and the *smallest thing that is above the interval*. The algorithm goes like this:

```
Input: the size of the array.
Yield the first item -- if there is one
Yield the last item -- if it is different from the first item.
Make a queue of intervals.
Enqueue the interval (0, array.Length - 1) 
While the queue is not empty:
    Dequeue the queue to obtain the current item.
    Is the interval empty? If so, skip this interval
    Otherwise, the interval has a GLB, a LUB, and a value in the middle.
    Yield the middle of the interval
    Enqueue the interval (bottom, middle)
    Enqueue the interval (middle, top)
```

Let's work the example above. We have the array `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ`.

```
Yield A
Yield Q
Enqueue A-Q. The queue is now A-Q
Is the queue empty? No.
Dequeue the queue. It is now empty.
current is A-Q
Is the current interval empty? no.
The middle is I.
Yield I.
Enqueue A-I. The queue is now A-I.
Enqueue I-Q. The queue is now A-I, I-Q.
Is the queue empty? No.
Dequeue the queue. It is now I-Q.
current is A-I.
Is the current interval empty? No.
The middle is E.
Yield E.
Enqueue A-E. The queue is now I-Q, A-E.
Enqueue E-I. The queue is now I-Q, A-E, E-I
Is the queue empty? No.
Dequeue. The queue is now A-E, E-I
current is I-Q
The middle is M
Yield M.
Enqueue I-M
Enqueue M-Q.  The queue is now A-E, E-I, I-M, M-Q
OK, let's start skipping some steps here. The state of the queue and the yields are:
Yield C
E-I, I-M, M-Q, A-C, C-E
Yield G
I-M, M-Q, A-C, C-E, E-G, G-I
Yield K
M-Q, A-C, C-E, E-G, G-I, I-K, K-M
yield O
A-C, C-E, E-G, G-I, I-K, K-M, M-O, O-Q
yield B
C-E, E-G, G-I, I-K, K-M, M-O, O-Q, A-B, B-C
OK, skip more steps...
Yield D, F, H, J, L, N, P
Queue is now A-B, B-C, C-D, D-E, ... P-Q
Every interval is now empty, so we skip all of htem and we are done.
```

Make sense?

The trick here is to notice that the order you want is a *breadth-first visit of a tree*. You just have to be able to "see through" the array to the tree structure that you want to traverse.

Incidentally, the ordering seems a bit weird. The ordering for the most part seems to be "divide the range into two parts and yield the middle of each range first".  Why then are the two extremes yielded *first*, instead of *last*?  I would find the ordering:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ
        I
    E       M
  C   G   K   O
 B D F H J L N P
A               Q
```

more intuitively obvious; if the things "in the middle" always get priority over things "at the extremes" then the extremes should go last, not first.

Comment: Thanks Eric.. that looks like the pattern I'm after. Will just need to think about how to implement your algorithm.... ta.

Comment: Thanks very much Eric.. I follow what you're doing now.. and will work on the code.

Comment: I'm looking at ways to speed up some spatial algorithms... the stuff very near, and very far away are the most important for what I'm doing. Then everything in between....

Comment: @timemirror That sounds like the reverse of pixellating an image - you improve the detail step by step by adding the intermediate values.

Comment: @Neil - yer, very similar to that. If the crude information still works then keep adding more detail until it breaks. Often spatially close things are similar, so it's a waste of time to look incrementally... instead by jumping around you can solve things faster. I'm just trying to find lots of ways to make those jumps and see which work better under different conditions. Then work out how to select the appropriate method each time. Thanks for your algorithm.. I'm trying that too.

Answer (score 2):

I can demonstrate a similar selection; it results in a slightly different order to yours.

Take the numbers 0 to 7, and express them in binary: `000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111`.

Now, reverse them: `000 100 010 110 001 101 011 111`.

In decimal, this gives 0 4 2 6 1 3 5 7. So you start with the first element, then halfway through the rest of the elements, then a quarter and three quarters, and then finally all the odd-numbered elements.

Obviously this procedure only works for exact powers of two.

Comment: Thanks Neil.. that's a pretty cool idea for a different sorting order.